# Nodetool Rebuild :- Stream Failing afer sometime

Tags: database, cassandra, database-migration

I have added a new node to my existing **single node** cassandra cluster. It has around 48gb of data. 
There is only one keyspace responsible for that and it has a **replication factor** of **'2'**(I changed it after adding the new node). I am trying to run nodetool rebuild on the new node so data can be streamed to it from the seed node.
 The stream ended after transferring **36gb** of data and the node went down. So I repeated the process but the stream keeps on failing after transferring some data (12-25 gb).
It ends with the following error.

```
error: Error while rebuilding node: Stream failed
-- StackTrace --
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while rebuilding node: Stream failed
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.rebuild(StorageService.java:1319)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.StandardMBeanIntrospector.invokeM2(StandardMBeanIntrospector.java:112)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.StandardMBeanIntrospector.invokeM2(StandardMBeanIntrospector.java:46)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MBeanIntrospector.invokeM(MBeanIntrospector.java:237)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.PerInterface.invoke(PerInterface.java:138)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MBeanSupport.invoke(MBeanSupport.java:252)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1468)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1309)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1401)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:829)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor6.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:357)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:573)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:834)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:688)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:687)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

P.S. I have made sure that the streaming_socket_timeout_in_ms is set to at least 24 hours. 
Kindly help me out here guys.

Thanks.

Update :- 
I ran **nodetool rebuild keyspace_name**  instead of **nodetool rebuild** and it ended with this error again.

```
WARN  [StreamReceiveTask:9] 2019-10-23 11:14:41,522 StreamResultFuture.java:214 - [Stream #b9b051b0-f580-11e9-92dd-9765711f899a] Stream failed
ERROR [RMI TCP Connection(12)-10.128.1.3] 2019-10-23 11:14:42,316 StorageService.java:1318 - Error while rebuilding node
org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamException: Stream failed
        at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamResultFuture.maybeComplete(StreamResultFuture.java:215) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.4.jar:3.11.4]
        at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamResultFuture.handleSessionComplete(StreamResultFuture.java:191) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.4.jar:3.11.4]
        at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamSession.closeSession(StreamSession.java:481) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.4.jar:3.11.4]
        at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamSession.onError(StreamSession.java:571) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.4.jar:3.11.4]
        at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamReceiveTask$OnCompletionRunnable.run(StreamReceiveTask.java:281) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.4.jar:3.11.4]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[na:1.8.0_222]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_222]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[na:1.8.0_222]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[na:1.8.0_222]
        at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.NamedThreadFactory.lambda$threadLocalDeallocator$0(NamedThreadFactory.java:81) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.4.jar:3.11.4]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_222]
INFO  [Service Thread] 2019-10-23 11:14:43,223 GCInspector.java:284 - ConcurrentMarkSweep GC in 310ms.  CMS Old Gen: 2391324840 -> 639245216; Code Cache: 38320192 -> 38627904; Compressed Class Space: 554$
ERROR [STREAM-IN-/10.128.1.1:7000] 2019-10-23 11:14:48,769 StreamSession.java:593 - [Stream #b9b051b0-f580-11e9-92dd-9765711f899a] Streaming error occurred on session with peer 10.128.1.1
java.lang.RuntimeException: Outgoing stream handler has been closed
        at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.ConnectionHandler.sendMessage(ConnectionHandler.java:143) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.4.jar:3.11.4]
        at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamSession.receive(StreamSession.java:655) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.4.jar:3.11.4]
        at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamSession.messageReceived(StreamSession.java:523) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.4.jar:3.11.4]
        at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.ConnectionHandler$IncomingMessageHandler.run(ConnectionHandler.java:317) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.4.jar:3.11.4]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_222]
```

**Update 2 :-**
I tried to do nodetool rebuild again on a fresh node
The stream fails again after transfering around 95% of data.
This is the log of streaming node

```
INFO  [STREAM-INIT-/10.128.1.3:56486] 2019-10-23 11:16:03,497 StreamResultFuture.java:116 - [Stream #80136bd0-f586-11e9-92dd-9765711f899a ID#0] Creating new streaming plan for Rebuild
INFO  [STREAM-INIT-/10.128.1.3:56486] 2019-10-23 11:16:03,498 StreamResultFuture.java:123 - [Stream #80136bd0-f586-11e9-92dd-9765711f899a, ID#0] Received streaming plan for Rebuild
INFO  [STREAM-INIT-/10.128.1.3:56488] 2019-10-23 11:16:03,498 StreamResultFuture.java:123 - [Stream #80136bd0-f586-11e9-92dd-9765711f899a, ID#0] Received streaming plan for Rebuild
INFO  [STREAM-IN-/10.128.1.3:56488] 2019-10-23 11:16:03,600 StreamResultFuture.java:173 - [Stream #80136bd0-f586-11e9-92dd-9765711f899a ID#0] Prepare completed. Receiving 0 files(0.000KiB), sending 133 f$
INFO  [Service Thread] 2019-10-23 11:19:14,472 GCInspector.java:284 - ParNew GC in 517ms.  CMS Old Gen: 104131728 -> 121315352; Par Eden Space: 1342177280 -> 0; Par Survivor Space: 67963984 -> 61263088
ERROR [STREAM-IN-/10.128.1.3:56488] 2019-10-23 11:56:43,902 StreamSession.java:706 - [Stream #80136bd0-f586-11e9-92dd-9765711f899a] Remote peer 10.128.1.3 failed stream session.
INFO  [IndexSummaryManager:1] 2019-10-23 11:58:32,284 IndexSummaryRedistribution.java:77 - Redistributing index summaries
INFO  [STREAM-IN-/10.128.1.3:56488] 2019-10-23 11:59:38,687 StreamResultFuture.java:187 - [Stream #80136bd0-f586-11e9-92dd-9765711f899a] Session with /10.128.1.3 is complete
ERROR [STREAM-OUT-/10.128.1.3:56486] 2019-10-23 11:59:38,688 StreamSession.java:593 - [Stream #80136bd0-f586-11e9-92dd-9765711f899a] Streaming error occurred on session with peer 10.128.1.3
java.lang.RuntimeException: Transfer of file /var/lib/cassandra/data/thingsboard/ts_kv_cf-53b7bf3096ec11e99154356269723c5c/md-583-big-Data.db already completed or aborted (perhaps session failed?).
        at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.messages.OutgoingFileMessage.startTransfer(OutgoingFileMessage.java:119) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.4.jar:3.11.4]
        at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.messages.OutgoingFileMessage$1.serialize(OutgoingFileMessage.java:49) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.4.jar:3.11.4]
        at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.messages.OutgoingFileMessage$1.serialize(OutgoingFileMessage.java:41) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.4.jar:3.11.4]
        at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.messages.StreamMessage.serialize(StreamMessage.java:50) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.4.jar:3.11.4]
        at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.ConnectionHandler$OutgoingMessageHandler.sendMessage(ConnectionHandler.java:408) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.4.jar:3.11.4]
        at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.ConnectionHandler$OutgoingMessageHandler.run(ConnectionHandler.java:380) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.4.jar:3.11.4]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_222]
WARN  [STREAM-IN-/10.128.1.3:56488] 2019-10-23 11:59:38,688 StreamResultFuture.java:214 - [Stream #80136bd0-f586-11e9-92dd-9765711f899a] Stream failed
INFO  [STREAM-INIT-/10.128.1.3:56674] 2019-10-23 12:03:24,860 StreamResultFuture.java:116 - [Stream #1da92910-f58d-11e9-92dd-9765711f899a ID#0] Creating new streaming plan for Rebuild
INFO  [STREAM-INIT-/10.128.1.3:56674] 2019-10-23 12:03:24,861 StreamResultFuture.java:123 - [Stream #1da92910-f58d-11e9-92dd-9765711f899a, ID#0] Received streaming plan for Rebuild
INFO  [STREAM-INIT-/10.128.1.3:56676] 2019-10-23 12:03:24,861 StreamResultFuture.java:123 - [Stream #1da92910-f58d-11e9-92dd-9765711f899a, ID#0] Received streaming plan for Rebuild
INFO  [STREAM-IN-/10.128.1.3:56676] 2019-10-23 12:03:24,950 StreamResultFuture.java:173 - [Stream #1da92910-f58d-11e9-92dd-9765711f899a ID#0] Prepare completed. Receiving 0 files(0.000KiB), sending 133 f$
INFO  [Service Thread] 2019-10-23 12:04:18,160 GCInspector.java:284 - ParNew GC in 307ms.  CMS Old Gen: 124972984 -> 125070416; Par Eden Space: 1342177280 -> 0; Par Survivor Space: 61042328 -> 82423296
INFO  [GossipStage:1] 2019-10-23 12:27:39,200 Gossiper.java:1026 - InetAddress /10.128.1.3 is now DOWN
INFO  [HANDSHAKE-/10.128.1.3] 2019-10-23 12:27:39,424 OutboundTcpConnection.java:561 - Handshaking version with /10.128.1.3
ERROR [STREAM-IN-/10.128.1.3:56676] 2019-10-23 12:27:45,107 StreamSession.java:593 - [Stream #1da92910-f58d-11e9-92dd-9765711f899a] Streaming error occurred on session with peer 10.128.1.3
java.net.SocketException: End-of-stream reached
        at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.messages.StreamMessage.deserialize(StreamMessage.java:71) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.4.jar:3.11.4]
        at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.ConnectionHandler$IncomingMessageHandler.run(ConnectionHandler.java:311) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.4.jar:3.11.4]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_222]
INFO  [STREAM-IN-/10.128.1.3:56676] 2019-10-23 12:27:45,108 StreamResultFuture.java:187 - [Stream #1da92910-f58d-11e9-92dd-9765711f899a] Session with /10.128.1.3 is complete
ERROR [STREAM-OUT-/10.128.1.3:56674] 2019-10-23 12:27:45,108 StreamSession.java:593 - [Stream #1da92910-f58d-11e9-92dd-9765711f899a] Streaming error occurred on session with peer 10.128.1.3
org.apache.cassandra.io.FSReadError: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.ChannelProxy.transferTo(ChannelProxy.java:145) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.4.jar:3.11.4]
        at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.compress.CompressedStreamWriter.lambda$write$0(CompressedStreamWriter.java:85) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.4.jar:3.11.4]
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.BufferedDataOutputStreamPlus.applyToChannel(BufferedDataOutputStreamPlus.java:350) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.4.jar:3.11.4]
        at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.compress.CompressedStreamWriter.write(CompressedStreamWriter.java:85) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.4.jar:3.11.4]
        at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.messages.OutgoingFileMessage.serialize(OutgoingFileMessage.java:101) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.4.jar:3.11.4]
        at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.messages.OutgoingFileMessage$1.serialize(OutgoingFileMessage.java:52) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.4.jar:3.11.4]
        at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.messages.OutgoingFileMessage$1.serialize(OutgoingFileMessage.java:41) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.4.jar:3.11.4]
        at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.messages.StreamMessage.serialize(StreamMessage.java:50) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.4.jar:3.11.4]
        at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.ConnectionHandler$OutgoingMessageHandler.sendMessage(ConnectionHandler.java:408) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.4.jar:3.11.4]
        at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.ConnectionHandler$OutgoingMessageHandler.run(ConnectionHandler.java:380) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.4.jar:3.11.4]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_222]
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
        at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.transferTo0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_222]
        at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.transferToDirectlyInternal(FileChannelImpl.java:428) ~[na:1.8.0_222]
        at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.transferToDirectly(FileChannelImpl.java:493) ~[na:1.8.0_222]
        at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.transferTo(FileChannelImpl.java:605) ~[na:1.8.0_222]
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.ChannelProxy.transferTo(ChannelProxy.java:141) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.4.jar:3.11.4]
        ... 10 common frames omitted
WARN  [STREAM-IN-/10.128.1.3:56676] 2019-10-23 12:27:45,108 StreamResultFuture.java:214 - [Stream #1da92910-f58d-11e9-92dd-9765711f899a] Stream failed
INFO  [RMI TCP Connection(124)-10.128.1.1] 2019-10-23 12:28:19,854 Gossiper.java:525 - Removing host: 0e8ad28d-6cc2-46df-8d3f-f346d464db40
INFO  [RMI TCP Connection(124)-10.128.1.1] 2019-10-23 12:28:19,854 Gossiper.java:526 - Sleeping for 30000ms to ensure /10.128.1.3 does not change
INFO  [RMI TCP Connection(124)-10.128.1.1] 2019-10-23 12:28:49,854 Gossiper.java:533 - Advertising removal for /10.128.1.3
INFO  [RMI TCP Connection(124)-10.128.1.1] 2019-10-23 12:28:50,245 StreamResultFuture.java:90 - [Stream #aae08f50-f590-11e9-9934-850cf6bcace3] Executing streaming plan for Restore replica count
INFO  [MiscStage:1] 2019-10-23 12:28:50,247 StorageService.java:4459 - Received unexpected REPLICATION_FINISHED message from /10.128.1.1. Was this node recently a removal coordinator?
INFO  [RMI TCP Connection(124)-10.128.1.1] 2019-10-23 12:28:50,248 StorageService.java:2584 - Removing tokens [-9135980046459212380, -9100471967410923634, -9097242662756219549, -8974765285872613713, -895$
INFO  [RMI TCP Connection(124)-10.128.1.1] 2019-10-23 12:28:50,317 Gossiper.java:557 - Completing removal of /10.128.1.3
INFO  [HANDSHAKE-/10.128.1.3] 2019-10-23 12:31:35,019 OutboundTcpConnection.java:561 - Handshaking version with /10.128.1.3
```

I am totally clueless about why it's failing.
Can anyone point me in the right drection ?
I have made sure that the there is no firewall issue also I am not using SSL for internode communication.

Comment: Have you observed the load on the machines? We had issues where cpu load was at 100% and streaming was failing.

Comment: I haven't checked that since it is remote. Can you take a look at the updated error_log

Comment: I checked the load on the streaming node, it's normal

Comment: @DarkAngel I need some context on the topology:
- You have 1 cluster, with 1 logical DC and 1 node. 
- You want to expand to 1 cluster in 1 DC with 2 nodes in the 1 dc. 
You shouldn't be using rebuild, you should stand the node up with `auto_bootstrap: true` and allow it to join normally. 
Is there a reason why you're using rebuild and not adding the node normally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
org.apache.cassandra.io.FSReadError: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
```

There could be a number of reasons for this (corrupted data, networking problems, schema issues between the two nodes) but basically it means the connection is getting severed and killing off the streaming in progress.

Networking issues are most likely. If you have any networking metrics try to use those for debbugging the connection.

There are a few things you can do to try to be clever here, the main thing is reduce the volume of streaming you need to do. You can achieve this by:

1. reducing the keyspace RF back to 1
2. Adding the node using `auto_bootstrap: true` in cassandra.yaml
3. Re-increasing the RF back to 2
4. Repairing the data

This will yield the same outcome where you've created 2 nodes that both contain 100% of the data, but during the node standup process, you only streamed 1/2 of that data. The repairs then in smaller sessions (smaller units of work) restored any other data that was missing to get you back to 100%.

**On a side-note** my advice would be for you to start regularly snapshotting your node, as there appear to be signs of bad health. Running a single node of Cassandra means you're not really protected from data loss, thats why C* is distrubuted and why replication_factor 3 is recommended for most setups.

Comment: Hmm, as I was running out of time I used snapshots to transfer all data.

Comment: I just wanted to migrate all data from existing single node cluster to a newly created one. I thought the best way would be to add the node and let Cassandra bootstrap it automatically. I never really figured out how auto_bootstrap works. Does th new node automatically starts copying data to itself ? It's kinda difficult to figure out the exact cause of the "broken pipe" error.